# Android: HttpClient parameters - Connection and Socket Timeout

Tags: android, http-post, httpclient

I could't find any helpful tutorials on internet nor the documentation on developers site.

In my application i am connecting to a Web Server using HttpPost, when there is **no internet** connection, but **wifi** is on it shows a white screen and after some 10-15 secs "UnknownHostException".

I caught this Exception and made toast like

```
Unable to connect, check your internet connection.
```

and close the Activity (or the Application, since i am using finish() on the 1st Activity).

When the **wifi** itself is off i get an instant toast like"

```
You need internet connection to use this Application
```

but the 1st case is irritating. Taking 10-15 secs time and then showing the toast.

So i used **HttpParameters** and added a **5 sec ConnectionTimeout** parameter.

But the application works same as before(no effect of this parameters).

How can i track if i hit ConnectionTime(5 secs over). So that i can show a Toast like

```
Slow internet connection
```

moreover why is the internet connection check not working when **wifi is on but no internet**

this is what i check when my application is lauched:

```
cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

if (isOnline(cm, this, SignUpActivity.this)){
//continue
}

public static boolean isOnline(ConnectivityManager cm, Context c, Activity a) {

    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }

    Toast.makeText(c, "You need internet access to run this application",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    a.finish();
    return false;
}
```

am i only checking whether device's wifi is on. if so, how can i check whether i have internet connection, instead of just wifi

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the first question, try using [SocketTimeout](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29) instead.

As for the second question, the line

```
NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
```

Will **only get Wi-fi status** (i.e. phone wifi antenna turned on) but not actual connectivity. The function returns immediately, so that if wifi is turned off you can toast out without checking connection further. But when wi-fi is turned on, you should go on and check your server's actual reachability, with something like

```
InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeOut)
```

Comment: Actually i am using SocketTimeout also. Sry i didn't mention it in the question. As for the 2nd solution, you mean i am just checking if wifi is on? I must change it o if wifi is on check if internet access is available?

Comment: the second one. When wi-fi is on, and only in that case, check your actual server reachability

Comment: in my app this code works:HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
   int timeoutConnection = serverTimeout;
   HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);HttpResponse response;response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

Comment: I actually followed this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/android-detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available#answers-header  where it says  cm.getActiveNetworkInfo(); alone is enough to know if internet access is there

Comment: that's not enough. The answer you posted says:"Note that having an active network interface doesn't guarantee that a particular networked service is available. Networks issues, server downtime, low signal, captive portals, content filters and the like can all prevent your app from reaching a server"

Comment: what do you mean by "in my app this code works". If you are unnable to connect to the server in time, what happens?

Comment: it gives a ConnectionTimeoutException, as expected

Comment: note that, since your "network" code should be in a separate thread, for Toast to show you may have to use runOnUiThread(Runnable)

Comment: but my network code is not in a separate thread. I know i should do that, but will change later.Even here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts#answers-header it says cm.getActiveNetworkInfo(); is enough. Do you know to checkif internet connection is available??

Comment: and usually in applications if a ConnectionTimeOutException Occurs. What will be the resultant action?? close the application??because you cannot say anything like "ConnectionTimeOut hence closing" as the user might want to wait for more time.